# temporarily allow java through windows firewall?

Tags: windows-7, java

I tried going to this site [netalyzr berkeley](http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/)   and it wants to run java. But this could've been any site. I know there's no harm in this one but it's jut an example.

I clicked Run to run the java plugin.

At some point a window came up asking me if i'd allow it through the firewall. I only want to temporarily. So if another java plugin wanted to run, I want the window to come up asking me for that one too.  Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: I doubt it's possible; firewall rules are applied to processes, not their actions. It would be nice if somebody knows the solution, though.

Comment: @gronostaj i'm sure some of the "personal firewall" type software like zonealarm might give options like 'just this time' rather than just always or never.

Comment: A possible workaround is to use something like NoScript (on firefox - or NotScript on Chrome) so you can automatically block Java on the browser, and set to click to play. So even if Java have internet access, your browser is the stopping stone that prevents Java from running.

Comment: @Darius it's not really a workaround 'cos if I  wanted it to run and my firewall prompted me, then there's going to be an exception in my firewall that I don't want to stay there. (I use the click to play feature in chrome).